# Best method to check a destination directory for newer files than a source directory

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a source directory and a destination directory. I want to ensure that everything in the source directory is either the same age or newer than the items in the destination directory.

What is the best method on windows, preferably powershell but I'm not opposed to something like robocopy if faster.

My initial thought is that something like this:

```
$src = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path C:\temp\src\
$dest = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path C:\temp\dest\
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $dest -DifferenceObject $src
## TODO: Check result of Compare-Object and throw error if there's an unexpected change?
```

Will probably have the information required as long as all SideIndicators point the right way, so I could use this to detect unexpected changes in the destination, but this approach seems non-obvious and convoluted so I'm wondering if there's a better way before I go down this path.

(Use case is that no-one should be modifying the destination except through a devops pipeline, but sometimes people do, so if there's an unexpected modified or new file in the destination I want to check up front and terminate the pipeline for further investigation before trying to deploy any files)

Comment: I would suggest that the better approach would be to create a new group that the file is owned by.  Then give the people that need it, write access.  If its an automated process, then run it as a user belonging to that group.

Comment: @RohitGupta that certainly is a better approach, but when you have a large organisation with many people involved, some with full admin\domain-admin access to the server in question, sometimes people still modify things they shouldn't... :(

Comment: That is why it's only a comment.  I went through the same issue with my organisation.  Even after leveraging the OS (Windows), it was still happening.  In my case, they were archives of complete application distribution with source.  They still kept getting modified.  I would manually check every few days with Beyond Compare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the file structure I created to test with their attributes:

```
PS C:\> Get-ChildItem C:\temp2\src -recurse

    Directory: C:\temp2\src

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                                           
----                 -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                                           
-a----         8/27/2022   9:58 PM              3 myfile1.txt                                                                                                                    
-a----         8/27/2022   9:59 PM              6 myfile2.txt

PS C:\> Get-ChildItem C:\temp2\dest -recurse

    Directory: C:\temp2\dest

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                                           
----                 -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                                           
-a----         8/27/2022   9:58 PM              3 myfile1.txt                                                                                                                    
-a----         8/27/2022   9:58 PM              3 myfile2.txt
```

There are two directories, SRC and DEST, each with 2 files. One of the files (myfile2.txt) has a different value of LastWriteTime. When we run the below code, it will tell us that there are a SRC and DEST mismatch regarding that file specifically and not give any feedback on the files that are the same.

In the following snippet, only change the values of `$srcFiles` and `$destFiles` to edit your paths. Nothing else will need to change.

```
$Results = @()
$srcFiles = Get-ChildItem "C:\temp2\src" -recurse | select Name,LastWriteTime
$destFiles = Get-ChildItem "C:\temp2\dest" -recurse | select Name,LastWriteTime
$srcFileTable = @{}
$destFileTable = @{}

foreach($srcFile in $srcFiles)
{
    $srcFileTable.Add(($srcFile.Name),($srcFile.LastWriteTime))
}
foreach($destFile in $destFiles)
{
    $destFileTable.Add(($destFile.Name),($destFile.LastWriteTime))
}

$srcFileTable.keys | %{
    if ($destFileTable.keys -match $_){
        if (!($destFileTable.$_ -match $srcFileTable.$_)) {
            $Results += new-object psobject -property @{Hash="SRC";Key=$_;Value=$srcFileTable.$_}
        }
    } Else {$Results += new-object psobject -property @{Hash="SRC";Key=$_;Value=$srcFileTable.$_}}
}
$destFileTable.keys | %{
    if ($srcFileTable.keys -match $_){
        if (!($srcFileTable.$_ -match $destFileTable.$_)) {
            $Results += new-object psobject -property @{Hash="DEST";Key=$_;Value=$destFileTable.$_}
        }
    } Else {$Results += new-object psobject -property @{Hash="DEST";Key=$_;Value=$destFileTable.$_}}
}
$Results | select Hash,Key,Value | sort -property Key,Hash | FT
```

After you run this, you will get a result that looks like the following:

```
Hash Key         Value               
---- ---         -----               
DEST myfile2.txt 8/27/2022 9:58:37 PM
SRC  myfile2.txt 8/27/2022 9:59:09 PM
```

This shows you that the SRC and DEST filename have different `LastWriteTime`s and you can deduce in this case that someone edited the SRC file for myfile2.txt and it is different from the one in dest.

Comment: Thanks, I'll test this when I have a chance! As a bonus what would be the easiest way to just terminate the script and throw an error when it detects the first file that is newer in the dest than the src - I want to put this before an automated deployment pipeline - basically to terminate the pipeline for manual checking\intervention before overwriting any potentially important changes people have made directly in test or prod environments...